# Unit Testing - best practice for multiple runs

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2013

I want to find the best way (least code/effort) to run a bunch of different tests with changing data and environment.

For example right now I have a test:

```
public void TestI32(Type inspectable, MemberInfo member)
{
Assert...
}
```

What I'd like:

```
[TestMethod]
public void ClassTests()
{
  var arg1 = ...
  TestI32(arg1, arg2, "Class");
  TestI16(arg1, arg2, "Class");
  TestFoo(arg1, arg2, "Class");
  TestBar(arg1, arg2, "Class");  
}
```

And have each method call show up as a separate test with that string as part of the name.

I'd also like to repeat all the tests from a 32bit and 64bit process. I recently discovered a bug that only showed up in unit tests and only because mstest runs tests under a 32bit process (a lot of unsafe code ...

Also, I'm not tied to using mstest but visual studio Integration would be nice. In the future, easy integration with a build script / continuous integration would be nice too.

Comment: Take a look at XUnit, you can set up `Theory`'s and `InlineData` to call the same test method multiple times (and shows up as multiple tests). I think there is similar functionality in NUnit, and both have VS integration.

Comment: Thanks Ron, I don't think inline data will work as it is applied through an attribute and I need to do some setup of the data/args before running the test.

Comment: I don't know about XUnit, but I can confirm that NUnit supports repeatedly calling the same test with different data via a data source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get each test to show up as a different reported result, then wrap the TestI32 in each set of conditions. Kind of like this...

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestA()
{
  var result = TestI32(arg1, arg2);
  Assert.IsTrue(result); // or whatever your assertion is.
}

[TestMethod]
public void TestB()
{
  var result = TestI32(arg3, arg4);
  Assert.IsFalse(result); // or whatever your assertion is.
}
```

Bitness should not matter from a test execution perspective, you are testing the code and not its dependencies. Consider focusing your testing in the areas around the bug (if its truly a bug in bitness and not your code).

You can turn on 64bit testing in VS 2013 (full instructions [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee782531.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396))

> From the Visual Studio menu, choose Test, then choose Settings, and
>   then choose Processor Architecture. Choose x64 to run the tests as a
>   64-bit process.

Comment: Thanks Stingy,
Is there anyway to do This:

[TestMethod]
public void ClassTests()
{
  var arg1 = ...
  TestI32(arg1, arg2, "Class");
  TestI16(arg1, arg2, "Class");
  TestFoo(arg1, arg2, "Class");
  TestBar(arg1, arg2, "Class");  
}
And have each method call show up as a seperate test with that string as part of the name?

Comment: No. Each [TestMethod] is going to be a separate test and result. The snippet for test methods is pretty easy though... "testm" + tab + tab  . You can also use a TT file to generate them if its overly repetitive.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind using NUnit (you can have VS integration if install the NUnit TestAdapter package from Nuget), you can make use of the [TestCaseSource](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=testCaseSource&r=2.5) attribute.  You can use this to point to a property/field or even a method.  So for example:

```
[TestCaseSource("SomeMethodSource")]
public void TestSomeStuff(int x, int y, string text) {
}

private IEnumerable SomeMethodSource() {
    int someValue = 1;
    return new object[] {
        new object [] {someValue++,2, "Case1"},
        new object [] {someValue++,5, "Case2"}
    };
}
```

Results in tests Named:

- TestSomeStuff(1,2,"Case1")
- TestSomeStuff(2,2,"Case2")

If you don't like the default naming, based on the arguments supplied to the test, you can also supply a TestName, although it's a bit more convoluted.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Xunit and its theory attribute in conjunction with the inlinedata attribute to pipe in your values